# How to paralellize a function with PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can I parallelize a function that runs over different filters of a dataframe using PySpark?

For example on this dataframe I would like to save the second position for each country. That is, rows:
***('us', 2, 34)*** 
and 
***('ca', 3, 98)***)

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
[
    ('us', 1, 55),
    ('us', 2, 34),
    ('us', 3, 56),
    ('ca', 3, 98),
    ('ca', 4, 65),
    ('ca', 1, 78)
],
["country", "position", "value"])

df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
```

The following code is returning an error:  TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable

```
countries_list = df.select(sf.collect_set('country').alias('country')).first()['country']

countries = sc.parallelize(countries_list)

# Process filtered country in df 
def process_country(df):
    position_lst = sorted(df.select(sf.collect_set('position').alias('position')).first()['position'])

    for i in position_lst:
        for j in position_lst:
            if j>i:
                row_to_save = df.filter(col('position').isin([j]))
                row_to_save.write.save('hdfs:///user/folder', format='parquet', mode='overwrite')
                break
        break

# filter main dataframe with country = x
def process(x): 
    df = sqlContext.table("df")
    df = df.filter(col('country').isin([x]) )
    process_country(df)


countries.foreach(process)
```

I am currently doing this through loops in python which is serializing all countries and hence taking too long. The goal is to be able to process all countries in parallel.

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 235, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 568, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 378, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 529, in save_function_tuple
    save(closure_values)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 606, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 639, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 378, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 529, in save_function_tuple
    save(closure_values)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 606, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 639, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 378, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 529, in save_function_tuple
    save(closure_values)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 606, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 639, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 378, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 529, in save_function_tuple
    save(closure_values)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 606, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 642, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 378, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 529, in save_function_tuple
    save(closure_values)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 606, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 642, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 378, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 529, in save_function_tuple
    save(closure_values)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 606, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 642, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 372, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 525, in save_function_tuple
    save(f_globals)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 804, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

Note: This is a simple example, in reality the actual function is very different and more complex. The main issue is figuring out how to parallelize functions of any kind where you need to apply it to different subsegments of a dataframe (avoiding serialization).

Comment: Post your stack trace. Where exactly are you getting the error?

Comment: This is the full error:

Comment: Are you sure your real problem is parallelizing function? To figure out 2nd position of each country is really simple sql statement which you can execute on temporary view using SparkSQL. If you want, I can post that as answer...

Comment: Yes, I just created this example for reference since it's easy to understand. In reality the function is very different and more complex. The issue is just understanding how to parallelize functions (of any kind but where you need to loop filtering a dataframe).

Comment: Have you looked at udfs? https://changhsinlee.com/pyspark-udf/

Comment: Yes, the problem I have found is that UDF operate row by row receiving columns references as inputs. Haven't been able to make them work by receiving the whole dataframe as worked over that (filtering).